# Save folder sorting just for that folder in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, sorting

I moved to Windows 10 (1607) from 7 a few days ago and while I'm fine with most of the new things, one is driving me crazy: Folder sorting

On my old box I had one folder always sorted by date in descending order (the Downloads folder) and every other folder sorted by name.

On my Windows 10 Box if I sort a folder by Date, all folders sort by date. I sorted one folder by name, clicked **Apply to Folders** under the View tab in the folder options, went to my Downloads folder and sorted by date. And voila, again every folder sorts by date.

Why isn't Windows 10 storing the sorting order for that one folder? How can I get the same behavior from Windows 7 back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This hasn't changed since Vista. There are 5 folder types (general, Dokuments, Pictures, Music, Videos) which you can customize. So if you download folder is type `general` all other folders which this type se the same view now if you click on apply to all folders.

Select any other type in the folder properties of your downloads folder and customize this one to sort via data.

Comment: I plugged in my old Windows 7 box, and yeah, it is still the same. The weird part is, if I open the folder from the pinned list, it is sorted by date, if I browse to it manually, it is sorted by name. Same on my Windows 7 box, I just always used it that way and never thought about it that way.